# Chating from several devices, using websocket

Tags: java, websocket, playframework-2.0, chat

I'm working on websocket chat at Play Framework. To the user could write with another device, it must first log out and login to one on the other. How to make so that the user could chat from different devices simultaneously without log out?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a joint identifier for that purpose: the username / email / id of the logged-in user, and a random number generated on the client-side used for connection. When you then connect to the server, group the connections of a given user under its primary identifier and broadcast the messages intended to one user to all of its connections. It should be easy to modify the chat example that comes with Play to match this construct.